# jquery swap dynamic images after document has loaded

Tags: jquery

I am using this tutorial:

http://www.devinrolsen.com/jquery-image-swapping-with-fade-effect/

But I cannot make it to work. I believe this is some conflict with my other scripts.

I have a catalogue with enters all jquery action in catalogue.php. Then a reader.php which displays either the catalogue or a single page. I have the simpletabs jquery script active.

Now I try to implement the jquery image swapping like in the tutorial above.

But the events for the image clicks are not started at all. I tried all the codes from the tutorial, but it does not work, it just loads the image in the window alone.

So I am trying to debug it, and just to show an alert box:

```
$("a.img_thumb").on("click", function (e) {
    alert('Works!');
});
```

But the alert is not triggered. (Although the other javascript is working, tabs, loader etc.)

I tried also:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.img_thumb").on("click", function (e) {
        alert('Works!');
    });
});
```

And now I tried this too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.img_thumb").on("click", function (e) {
        alert('Works!');
    });
});
```

These are all my jquery in the catalogue.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpletabs_1.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind('ajaxStart', function(){
        $('#loading').css("display", "block");
    }).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
        $('#loading').css("display", "none");
    });
    function show_object(itemid,object_type){
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "reader.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "id="+ itemid,
            dataType: "html"
        });
        $('table.object_list_' + object_type).hide();
        request.done(function(msg) {       
            $('div.show_object_' + object_type).append(msg);       
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    };
    $("a.img_thumb").on("click", function (e) {
        alert('Works!');
    });
</script>
```

Here is part of the source code, the images are created dynamically from a xml file

```
    <a href="http://domain.com/itemimages/img50293090.jpg" class="img_thumb">
<img src="http://domain.com/itemimages/img50293090.jpg" alt="pic" class="thumbnail"></a>
```

Thank you, I have no idea where the error is

**Additional info**

The two scripts, catalogue.php and reader.php build a catalogue. the names are not good, because the catalogue.php does not anything else than have some css and jquery. This is the whole script of catalogue.php:

```
<?php
//If needed, paste
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpletabs_1.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind('ajaxStart', function(){
            $('#loading').css("display", "block");
        }).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
            $('#loading').css("display", "none");
        });
        function show_object(itemid,object_type){
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "reader.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "id="+ itemid,
                dataType: "html"
            });
            $('table.object_list_' + object_type).hide();
            request.done(function(msg) {       
                $('div.show_object_' + object_type).append(msg);       
            });
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        };
        $(document.body).on("click", "a.img_thumb", function (e) {
            alert('Works!');
        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @import "css/simpletabs.css";
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        #loading {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;   
            left:30px;   
            top:90px;   
            z-index: 1000;          
        }
        img.list_image {
            heigth:90px; 
            width:90px;
        }
        td.list_info {
            width:150px;
        }
        p.tab_header {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        table.infotable {
            width:800px;
        }
        td.key {
            width:200px;
        }
        td.value {
            width:400px;
        }
        #show_info {
            width:50%;
            float:left;
        }

        #show_pictures {
            width:50%;
            float:right;
        }
        #show_maplinks {
            width:100%;
            clear:all;
        }
        #main_image {
            width:200px;
            margin:3px;
        }
        #thumbs {
            width:200px;
        }
        img.thumbnail {
            max-width:60px;
            max-height:60px;
            margin:3px;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="catalogue" class="simpleTabs">
        <img src="loading.gif" id="loading"/>
<?php
include('reader.php');
?>
    </div>
```

The reader.php show the list with the items, if $_GET['id'] is not set. If GET is set, then it shows the single item with a lot of data and the images.

The reader.php is almost 1000 lines so I will not post it here.

But, as discussed in the comments. could it be that the problem is somehow, because the images are loaded with ajax when the user clicks on one item at the list? So the images are not present at initial load

**Finally** I got something working, thanks to you all!

In reader.php where the images are created, I added an onclic-function:

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <?php foreach ($original_images as $image) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" class="img_thumb">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" alt="kuva" class="thumbnail" onclick="alertme()"/>
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And the jquery looks like this:

```
function alertme() {
    alert('Works!');
};
```

And this works. How this?

Comment: Haven't checked simpletags script yet, but have you tried with an older jquery version? 1.8.3 or 1.6.x?

Also `.on()` works on the parent if I'm correct.

Comment: you say the images are created dynamically, are they created before the eventlistener is created or afterwards? because that would be your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I tried both now, 183 and 161 .. both no change

Comment: $("a.img_thumb") on click event set should be done inside document.ready

Comment: @red-X the jquery is created on catalogue.php, which includes the reader.php (in reader.php the images are read) so I think the images are created afterwards?

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso thank you, I tried it (see edited post) but this does not help either! What I am doing incredibly wrong here?

Comment: Can I first ask, why not just use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)? It has [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and much more and is made specifically by and for jQuery!

Comment: if a simple click event on an image doesn't work there's something wrong in your page. Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: First problem, you're not putting your JavaScript in a loading event

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso sorry I have no idea how the fiddles are working. I am still new to jquery and javascript and feel so lost.

Comment: @SpYk3HH do you mean all jscript should be into an event? The scripts before worked fine like they are in the above post.. And still working. Only the thumbnail not

Comment: Is all that code in the same page?
Can you edit the question and post all the page code at once?

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso I added addional information to my question

Comment: SpYk3HH answer is partial correct. 
Do you now what DOM is and how it works? 
You're creating an html page with no <a> elements, set their click event and ONLY THEN loading the images.
You have to set the click event AFTER the loading.

Comment: One more thing. You're not loading the images, where is the call for reader.php? I can see you're using an ajax call but its inside a function that is never called.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso I include the reader.php at the bottom of catalogue.php with php. the ajax call is for fetching the single item and displaying it `onclick="show_object('<?php echo $itemId.','.$title; ?>')`

Comment: If the images are loaded with php they are loaded server side so it is after document.ready.
You have to explain your pipeline better.

Comment: Thank you my fault, I did not know that this could cause a problem (me->jquerynoob)

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso I was about to accept your answer with the explanation, found it the best, sorry that you deleted it

Comment: lol no problem, but that putting the onclick attribute at the <a> elements creation solves your problem cause that way the event is set onload.
Dont worry about that, it wasnt 100% right anyway. Your solution is similar and honestly easier to understand for begineers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that snippet is from your HEAD, then you're missing your "onload" event. Change your snippet too:

```
function show_object(itemid,object_type){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "reader.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "id="+ itemid,
        dataType: "html"
    });
    $('table.object_list_' + object_type).hide();
    request.done(function(msg) {       
        $('div.show_object_' + object_type).append(msg);       
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
};
$(function() {  //  $(document).load(function....
    $(document).bind('ajaxStart', function() {
        $('#loading').css("display", "block");
    })
    .bind('ajaxStop', function(){
        $('#loading').css("display", "none");
    });
    $("a.img_thumb").on("click", function (e) {
        alert('Works!');
    });
})
```

Also, this could be a "timing" issue. It could be your code is running BEFORE the HTML is "written" to the document body. Too test that, simply wrap your `work` in a timer and run it. Wait the time, then see if the events fire.

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(document).bind('ajaxStart', function() {
            $('#loading').css("display", "block");
        })
        .bind('ajaxStop', function(){
            $('#loading').css("display", "none");
        });
        $("a.img_thumb").on("click", function (e) {
            alert('Works!');
        });
    }, 3000);   //  3 second timer, this event won't be set till 3 seconds after the page is loaded
})
```

If this is a timing issue (dynamic data loaded after event listener set) then simply go to where you load the new HTML, and place your event code there. Make sure you place it at the end, after all new HTML is loaded and written.

Another thing you might do, is use the `delegate` side of `.on()`. This should add the event `click` to even `dynamic content`. This is usually my last resort, as I like control over pinpoint element events, but this is a "clean" way to maintain code in one place.

### Using .delegate()

```
$("body").on("click", "a.img_thumb", function (e) {
    alert('Works!');
});
```

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso Because of when the actual HTML is written. He said it's loaded dynamically. I've been in plenty of situations where dynamic HTML doesn't get event applied to it.

Comment: Oh yes, it is the case that the html of the images is loaded far after the jquery is initializes, because at the first call of the catalogue.php, I load a whole different html with the list of the items. If user click onto one item, then the images are loaded

Comment: -1, really? lol, As formentioned, the code works fine for me, but then, I'm not loading elements dynamically

Comment: @Kaktus that being the case, can you place you're `on click` event code at the same place as where you load the dynamic elements? That would probably help, a lot!

Comment: Im not sure im following...
If its loaded from server $(document).ready() makes sure to execute only after the dom is all created. If its dynamic load the onlick event have to be set on each load and the OP code makes no sense.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso welcome to the table, lol. That's what I was just figuring out with him. The HTML, as he just mentioned, is loaded "after the fact", thus the event setter is in the wrong place, thus the change in my answer, or rather, the extension. I was concerned he had loading HTML elsewhere (as I've done via MVC layouts) that was not loading till after the initial "doc.load" call. Situations which make sites load faster, but mean moving pieces of code.

Comment: I think your answer explains the problem but setTimeout is not a very good solution cause it can either take less time or much more time.
The best solution is to set click events after the loading, so, controlled load->set event pipeline

Comment: So now its showing the alert box! I learned that I have to create the click event when the images are displayed, not before. I hope I can now add the image swap functions from the tutorial into this function..

Comment: @Kaktus I made one new update at the end of my answer, something else for yout o check out.

Comment: Thank you! I am now getting it to work, with added the onclick="function" to the thumbnail itself. Then just in the function the whole image swap code and works perfectly!

Comment: @SpYk3HH I tried the last part of your edited answer, it is also not working for me. No idea why, but the onclick is working, and as long as its not bad practise, I go with it

Comment: @Kaktus that will work cause onclick is set only at load time. You can either do that or follow my answer and set it at ajax success calback

Comment: @Kaktus One last comment, if you read the Link i had added to the end of my answer, you'll find the best way to use the `delegate` side of `.on()` is by using the "parent>child" relationship. As such: `$("parent-selector").on("click", "child-selector", function (e) { /* do work */ });` I can't say for sure without sitting there testing your code, but if you were wanting to use that method (or just try it, as i know you have a solution now) it might not have worked do to the first selector being `body`. Just some more info for you to know. Try it, decide what best fits "you"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating eventlisteners for objects that don't exist yet, you can create the listener on a parent object(`body`, or a closer object would be even better)

Give this a try:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "a.img_thumb", function (e) {
    alert('Works!');
});
```

The listener is added to the body in this case, it's registered for the click event, but only if the click event is on a `a.img_thumb` within the `body`. This way the link's don't have to exist yet when you're adding the listener.

Comment: This is too strange but this is also not working. No change at all, when I click on the image, its just loaded, no jquery action at all :(